# Convert an arrays of array surrounded by quotes into string array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have date duration values in following format.

```
array1 = '[["2022-01-18","2022-01-21"],["2022-02-15","2022-02-17"], ...]';
```

And need to convert it as follows,

```
array2 = [ '2022-01-18 - 2022-01-21', '2022-02-15 - 2022-02-17', ... ]
```

For the work done I have followed two ways,

1. `formattedArray1 = array1.replace(/","/g, " - ").reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])`

this gives me an error:

> array2.reduce is not a function

2. `formattedArray2 = [].concat.apply([], array1.replace(/","/g, " - "));`
   and this gives me the error

> CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

To fix this any thought would be highly appreciated!

Comment: [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is a good start.

Comment: When giving an example it's best that they are comprised of valid objects (e.g., no `...`) so that all readers offering answers can apply their suggested code to the example you provide (e.g, `array1 = '[["2022-01-18","2022-01-21"],["2022-02-15","2022-02-17"]]';`). Also, `array1` is perhaps not the best name for a string. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've got there is an array serialised to JSON.

You can [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it to an array then map it to the value you want

```js
const array1 = '[["2022-01-18","2022-01-21"],["2022-02-15","2022-02-17"]]';

const arr = JSON.parse(array1);
const array2 = arr.map(([from, to]) => `${from} - ${to}`);
console.log(array2);
```

---

If you're curious (like I was) about the performance of the [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) vs [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), the results from https://jsbench.me are below...

> #### Template literal
>
> 2678.21 ops/s ± 0.85%
> **Fastest**

> #### Array.prototype.join()
>
> 1150.62 ops/s ± 0.51%
> 57.04 % slower

[image: benchmark results]

Answer (score 2):

`array1` is stored as `String`, so you need to convert it to Array to use `reduce` or other array methods.

```js
array1 = '[["2022-01-18","2022-01-21"],["2022-02-15","2022-02-17"]]';
arr = JSON.parse(array1)
formattedArray1 = arr.map((e) => e.join(" - "))
// ['2022-01-18 - 2022-01-21', '2022-02-15 - 2022-02-17']
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You are calling reduce on type string( `array1.replace(/","/g, " - ")` will return a string) , reduce works only with `Array.prototype` that's why you are getting `reduce` is not a function.

> array2.reduce is not a function error.

You need to parse the array before doing reduce.

```js
const array1 = '[["2022-01-18","2022-01-21"],["2022-02-15","2022-02-17"]]';
const parsedArr = JSON.parse(array1);
const result = parsedArr.map(date => date.join(" - ") )
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This gives me the required output.

Answer (score 2):

**Another Alternative**

The transform could also be done at the same time the json is parsed by providing a [reviver function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#syntax) that evaluates each key-value.  if the value is a child array then join the elements.

```js
let json = '[["2022-01-18","2022-01-21"],["2022-02-15","2022-02-17"]]';


let data = JSON.parse(json, (k,v) => k && v.push ? v.join(" - ") : v );


console.log(data);
```